# compare the elements of 2 circular arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, equals

How can I compare the elements of 2 circular arrays in java, to be in the same sequence
so per example(A,B,C,D,E,F) is equal to (D,E,F,A,B,C) but not equal to(D,F,E,A,B,C)

Comment: Are elements in the arrays unique? Are the lengths guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: are you using arrays? array lists?

Comment: What's the purpose and what have you tried so far ??

Comment: yes it is sure that they are the same elements and the same length, but the problem is to check the sequence

Comment: it should be using arrays